# Is there a canonical reason that the protagonist of the Mandalorian is still unnamed?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

To my knowledge those wearing Mandalorian armor have always had a proper name (e.g., Boba Fett, Jango Fett), as well as other works I'm not familar with, referenced [here in a Wikipedia article for Mandalorian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandalorian).

Now that the new Mandalorian series is 5 episodes deep, we've had at least two recurring characters who do not have a name.  (Frankly, hearing the main protagonist keep being called "Mando" is getting annoying)  Is it known whether this is typical of Mandalorian culture that they go unnamed?  Could this be part and parcel that the protagonist does not have a signet, and maybe also does not have a reputation?

Wouldn't the fact that the protagonist is the subject of a galaxy-wide bounty be reason enough that he should be named?

I am asking simply to see if there are any in-universe reasons why we haven't heard any names for any of these Mandalorians yet.

Comment: No most Mandalorians have names like Sabine Wren or even the heavy duty blue one from 1.03 is named Paz Vizla and may be an ascendant of character from the clone wars whom was also voiced by JF. The idea here is an allusion to "The Man with No Name". However I'm pretty sure "The Mando" has one, as Pascal let it slip once. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mandalorian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are correct. Most Mandalorians do have names...

> “**The character is very much built on the iconic presence of the Man
> With No Name in the Sergio Leone movies, played by Clint Eastwood**,
> [and] the lone samurai in Akira Kurosawa,” he said. “It’s
> aesthetically and very, very much narratively built in that kind of
> iconic lone gunslinger/sword-wielder.” -Pedro Pascal

As mentioned in a comment, actor Pedro Pascal had let his character's birth name slip in an early interview, but it had yet to be revealed on screen and/or with a lack of clarity that the character has kept his birth name, but the reveal of it implied, that while the series would intentionally play with '**[The Man With No Name](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment-arts/tv/story/2019-08-26/mandalorian-pedro-pascal-star-wars-disney-plus)'** allusions, it wouldn't do so forever...

Episode 1.08 (Redemption), the season one finale, changes that. His name is

> Din Djarin. This is the same name Pascal let slip prior to the series start.

In addition, looking at this from an in-universe perspective, one reason Mandalorians might not as freely be giving out their names, is because in this era they are on the verge of extinction and are in hiding.

> #### 1.03 The Sin Transcript:
>
> The Armorer: It will draw many eyes. These were cast in an Imperial
> smelter. **These are the spoils of the Great Purge. The reason that we
> live hidden like sand rats. Our secrecy is our survival. Our survival
> is our strength. Our strength was once in our numbers. Now we live in
> the shadows and only come above ground one at a time. Our world was
> shattered by the Empire, with whom this coward shares tables.**
>
> The Mandalorian: The Empire is no longer. And the Beskar has returned.
>
> The Armorer: When one chooses to walk the Way of the Mandalore, you
> are both hunter and prey. How can one be a coward if one chooses this
> way of life? Have you ever removed your helmet?
>
> The Mandalorian: No.
>
> The Armorer: Has it ever been removed by others?
>
> The Mandalorian: Never.
>
> The Armorer: This is the Way.

Episode 1.08 reconfirms these ideas that were laid out in 1.03 when the characters come across

> a pile of armor and Djarin talks once more with The Armorer.